# How to add the media attribute in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, video, html5-video

I’m using an HTML5 and jQuery interactive video gallery with a Flash fallback that I adapted from a tutorial. The site is fluid. I don’t know jQuery and I’m trying to get small mobile devices to play a video of smaller dimensions (480x272) than what's currently being served (800x450).

Here is how I’ve altered the code, but the media query is not being recognized. What are my formatting errors?

```
var videoCode = '<video width="'+480+'" height="'+272+'" controls autoplay autobuffer>
                 <source src="video/'+videoFile+'_small.ogv" type="video/ogg" media="screen and (max-width:500px)">
                 <source src="video/'+videoFile+'_small.mp4" type="video/mp4" media="screen and (max-width:500px)">
                 <video width="'+800+'" height="'+450+'" controls autoplay autobuffer>
                 <source src="video/'+videoFile+'.ogv" type="video/ogg" />
                 <source src="video/'+videoFile+'.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
```

Edit: fixed coding layout

Comment: var videoCode = '<video width="'+480+'" height="'+272+'" controls autoplay autobuffer><source src="video/'+videoFile+'_small.ogv" type="video/ogg" media="screen and (max-width:500px)"><source src="video/'+videoFile+'_small.mp4" type="video/mp4" media="screen and (max-width:500px)">
<video width="'+800+'" height="'+450+'" controls autoplay autobuffer><source src="video/'+videoFile+'.ogv" type="video/ogg" /><source src="video/'+videoFile+'.mp4" type="video/mp4" />

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems to be missing but to add/update an element's attribute is `$('someselector').attr('attrname', 'value');`

Comment: This is the part that precedes it, if that's what you mean:
var videoFile = $(this).attr('videofile');
var videoPoster = $(this).attr('videofile');
var videoWidth = Number($(this).attr('videowidth'));
var videoHeight = Number($(this).attr('videoheight'));

Comment: Thanks. Now, is jQuery not updaint attirubtes using the attr() method?

Comment: I've been learning about jQuery, and now realize that an "if...else" statement needs to be used instead of the media queries in the variable definition. 

Here's the current statement at the end of the variable definitions:

    $('#videoPlayer').html(videoCode);

And please excuse any errors in terminology! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
//var videoFile = $(this).attr('videofile');
    var videoFile = (screen.width < 500) ? $(this).attr('videofile') + "_small" : $(this).attr('videofile');
    var videoPoster = $(this).attr('videofile');
    var videoPoster = $(this).attr('videofile');
    var videoWidth = (screen.width < 500) ? 200 : 800;
    var videoHeight = (screen.height < 500) ? 200 : 450;
```

This proved to be the solution.